# Send Multi Select box Values with Ajax & PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, function

i have a problem in my php & ajax code so i have this Code

```
<select id='absence_reason[]' name='absence_reason[]'>
     <option value='1'>Value 1</option>
     <option value='2'>Value 2</option>
     <option value='3'>Value 3</option>
     <option value='4'>Value 4</option>
     <option value='5'>Value 5</option>
     <option value='6'>Value 6</option>
</select>

<select id='absence_reason[]' name='absence_reason[]'>
     <option value='1'>Value 1</option>
     <option value='2'>Value 2</option>
     <option value='3'>Value 3</option>
     <option value='4'>Value 4</option>
     <option value='5'>Value 5</option>
     <option value='6'>Value 6</option>
</select>
```

Now i want to Send the values of this 2 select boxes with AJAX & PHP :
Ok in Ajax i have write this code but is not work

```
    function adding_multi_absences() {
      var reason = new Array();
      $("input[name='absence_reason[]']:selected").each(function() {
            reason.push( $(this).val() );
      });

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "include/ajax/adding_multi_absences.php",
          data: {
              add_multi_reason:reason
          },
          beforeSend: function () { // Before Send the data do somthing
             $(".loader").fadeIn();
             $(".showing").fadeIn();
          },
          success: function(data) { // If Process Success do somthing in our case will be show some data in browser
             $("#resultshow").fadeIn().html(data);
          },
          error: function(err) {  // if Process Error
            alert(err);
          },
          complete: function() { // After complete all Request Do Somting
            $('.loader').fadeOut();
              setTimeout(get_student_for_multi_absences,2000); // Refresh Every X Seconde
          }

      });
}
```

and in my PHP File  this Code

### PHP File

```
                            if (!empty($_POST['add_multi_reason'])) {
                                // this variabel have Multi Values From CheckBox Of Select Student  who Absences in Each Class
          $reason                      =  $_POST['add_multi_reason'];
                                $date_D                      =  date('d');
                                $date_M                      =  date('m');
                                $date_Y                      =  date('Y');
                                $hours                       =  date('H');
                                $mins                        =  date('i');
                                $date_now                    =  date('Y-m-d');
                                foreach ($absences as $student_code) {
                                    add_absences($student_code,$reason,$admin_school_code,$date_D,$date_M,$date_Y,$hours,$mins,$admin_token,$admin_permission);
                                }
                                echo show_alert("success",$Lang['success_operation']);
                        }else{

                                echo show_alert("warning",$Lang['no_absence_selected']);
                        }
```

i want to send this 2 select box in data base but each one insert into a row thank you

Comment: 'i have a problem' - whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need value attribute name in form. Example :
Form

```
<form id="login_form">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="a"/>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="b"/>
    <button type="button" onclick="login()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
function login(){
  var obj = $('#login_form').serialize();
  $.post('index.php', obj, function(res){
    alert(res);
  })
}
```

PHP - index.php

```
<?php
if(!empty($POST['username']) && !empty($POST['password'])){
  $user = $POST['username'];
  $pass = $POST['password'];
  $res = "Username : ".$user." || Password : ".$pass;
  return $res;
}
?>
```

If you serialize the whole form as object and pass in URL you will get all possible and selected values.

HINT : below code will show you all received data. you can take alert in javascript.

```
<?php  
  print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your code a bit 
**1. that's how you get a value of select in array** 
   `$("select[name='absence_reason[]']").each(function() {
            reason.push( $(this).val() );
      })`
**2.then stringify your ajax reason array**
    `var data = {add_multi_reason: JSON.stringify(reason)};
                         $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "include/ajax/adding_multi_absences.php",
                            data: data,
                            beforeSend: function () { // Before Send the data do somthing
             $(".loader").fadeIn();
             $(".showing").fadeIn();
          },
          success: function(data) { // If Process Success do somthing in our case will be show some data in browser
             $("#resultshow").fadeIn().html(data);
          },
          error: function(err) {  // if Process Error
            alert(err);
          },
          complete: function() { // After complete all Request Do Somting
            $('.loader').fadeOut();
              setTimeout(get_student_for_multi_absences,2000); // Refresh Every X Seconde
          }
                        });`
**3. and that's how you get values of two selects in php**
    `$feedback = json_decode($_POST['add_multi_reason']);`
first select value `var_dump($feedback[0]);`
second select value `var_dump($feedback[1]);`

Comment: kindly add var_dump($_POST['add_multi_reason']) at the top of the block and then tell me the output